# Pass special character via href and $_GET

Tags: php, html

Here I am making a link using anchor tag. And upon clicking this link it shows a popup box. I am using greybox. And upon clicking I pass the value by putting it in the url. So I can grab it via $_GET in the popup that opens.

But upon opening the page I cannot pass special characters. I have no problems with `MAX9107ESA` for example. Since it is alphanumeric. But once I pass `MAX9175EUB+` for example, on the next page I will only get `MAX9175EUB` in the $_GET, but I see `MAX9175EUB+` in the url.

I usually uses encodeURIComponent in javascript. But since I am passing this via url and $_GET. Is there a way to like encodeURIComponent it before putting it in the url? If possible I'd like it to be pure html.

```
   foreach($maximumSetup as $key=>$value)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href='popupmaximumsetup.php?gFacility=".$value['FACILITY']."&gProduct=".$value['PRODUCT']."' rel='gb_page_center[500,500]'>".$value['MAXIMUM_SETUP']."</a>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Comment: use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) you would do this:

```
   foreach($maximumSetup as $key=>$value)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href='popupmaximumsetup.php?gFacility=".urlencode($value['FACILITY'])."&gProduct=".urlencode($value['PRODUCT'])."' rel='gb_page_center[500,500]'>".$value['MAXIMUM_SETUP']."</a>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```